# Directions of angular velocity and angular acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

How can the directions of angular velocity and angular acceleration be determined in the case of uniform circular motion?

Comment: Hey there John.I can't see what you answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is to use the right hand rule. Curl your fingers in the direction of linear velocity, and your thumb points in the direction of angular velocity. This allows one to talk about a fixed angular velocity for a rotating system.

For instance, if a fly is flying in counterclockwise circles on the plane of your computer screen, its angular velocity is towards you.

Comment: What about the angular acceleration? And is it just a convention or has some physical reasoning behind it?